# Spring Security: AccessDecisionVoter

Tags: java, spring, security, vote

```
@Service
public class MyVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Entity> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {        
        boolean myBool = false;
        return myBool;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == Project.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Entity someEntity,
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) {
        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Can you explain me, how the first supports method is supposed to work? No matter how i change myBool, the vote-method is always invoked. It seems like only supports(Class clazz) has effect on the invokation.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()               
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Bean
public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager() {
    Map<String, AccessDecisionVoter> beans = context
            .getBeansOfType(AccessDecisionVoter.class);

    List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>(
            beans.values());

    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    return affirmativeBased;
}
}
```

This is basically my only config.

This is how I used the AccessDecisionManager:

```
    /* AUTHORIZATION */
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();

    Collection<ConfigAttribute> config = new HashSet<ConfigAttribute>();
    config.add(new SecurityConfig("Something"));

    try {
        adm.decide(authentication, project, config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // .. Exception Handling
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your Spring Security Application Context Configuration, It is hard to give a correct answer but for your question, The Javadoc for the method states the following;

```
Indicates whether this AccessDecisionVoter is able to vote on the 
passed ConfigAttribute.
```

This method is actual invoked for `ConfigAttribute` like the following `"isAnonymous()"` for `WebExpressionVoter`

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*"
            access="isAnonymous()" />
</security:http>
```

Or for `RoleVoter` something like `"ROLE_ADMIN"`

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"
            access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</security:http>
```

Both `WebExpressionVoter` and `RoleVoter` are implementations of `AccessDecisionVoter`. Unless you are not trying to evaluate any `ConfigAttribute`s as mentioned above. Your method will never be invoked thus you won't see any effect whether you return `true` or `false`. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you look at the [AffirmativeBased](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.java) AccessDecisionManager's `decide` method.

```
public void More ...decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
46            throws AccessDeniedException {
47        int deny = 0;
48
49        for (AccessDecisionVoter voter : getDecisionVoters()) {
50            int result = voter.vote(authentication, object, configAttributes);
51
52            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
53                logger.debug("Voter: " + voter + ", returned: " + result);
54            }
55
56            switch (result) {
57            case AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED:
58                return;
59
60            case AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_DENIED:
61                deny++;
62
63                break;
64
65            default:
66                break;
67            }
68        }
69
70        if (deny > 0) {
71            throw new AccessDeniedException(messages.getMessage("AbstractAccessDecisionManager.accessDenied",
72                    "Access is denied"));
73        }
74
75        // To get this far, every AccessDecisionVoter abstained
76        checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions();
77    }
```

It doesn't make use of `supports(ConfigAttribute con)` method at all. Thus you have to modify your coding to check as below in order to it to work.

```
@Service
public class MyVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Entity> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {        
        boolean myBool = false;
        return myBool;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == Project.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Entity someEntity,
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> config) {
        if(supports(config)) { // Add this check
            return ACCESS_GRANTED;
        } else {
            return ACCESS_DENIED; // Abstain Based on your requirement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am using java-configuration only and I am pretty new to Spring so I do not really understand your answer. I use spring boot and only configured my access decision manager. I am using the access decision managers decide method in my controllers to decide whether the user is authorized to access an object. void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) I thought the configAttributes had any effect on my voters....?

Comment: Without Seeing your Java-Configuration and How you make use of the AccessDecisionManager in your controller it is difficult to answer further.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope this helps you to help me :)

Comment: Are you sure Map<String, AccessDecisionVoter> beans = context
            .getBeansOfType(AccessDecisionVoter.class); Returns only your AccessDecisionVoter

Comment: Yes. I know that my voter is called. vote() works just fine. I just dont get what the purpose of the supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) is / why it is not called.