# How to check hasRole in java code for URL

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have `RequestCache` from where i can get redirectURL where user will land after successful login. I am using spring security for the authentication.

Now I want to check through `Authentication` whether authority has access role for redirectURL.

*AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
        final Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    final RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    final SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
    String redirectURL = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl()
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    // Need to check redirectURL whether it is authorized or not
    ......
}
```

I know there is a way to check `hasRole` using request -> `request.isUserInRole(ROLE)` but in my case request is not giving that URL which i want to authorize.

My target URL is redirectURL which i can want to authorize. Please help.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by // Need to check redirectURL whether it is authorized or not ?

Comment: i want to check whether redirectURL is authorized by logged in user or not. The list of url i have defined in `spring-security.xml` file using security:intercept-url hasAnyRole for respective roles.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you like need custom access decision voter. Take a look at this article : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html   Basically you have already authenticated user but want to check if he is authorized to access certain resource. You can register your custom voter or alter existing. Take a look at this stackoverflow question [Spring Security: AccessDecisionVoter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587531/spring-security-accessdecisionvoter)